# VS Code Extension for Loading Source Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, vscode-extensions

I am interested in extending VS Code to load/edit/save project code, files, etc from a place other than the file system. For example, let's say I wanted to store my project in a database. I have looked at the extension API docs but didn't see anything obvious. Is there an API for extending VS Code in this way?

Comment: [My reaction to this post...](http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/but-why.gif)

Comment: Not surprising but not very helpful

Comment: Sorry, had to be done. On a side note this question is actually off-topic for Stack Overflow which is probably the reason there have been no responses. You might want to check [what's on topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and re-work your question with some more detail.

Comment: No worries, I expected such; most people havent seen systems operate like this. On the "off topic" thing - I don't really understand - my question seems to fit:
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: Ie, i'm asking - "what is the extensibility api to do this?" Isn't that specific enough?

Comment: Yes but read down to point 4... `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: I'm not asking for "best extensibility" or "best ide", there's no opinion or spam answers to this question. This is purely a factual answer - there's either an API that VS Code provides and someone knows it, or there's not.

Comment: Did you google it? I just found this is all of about 10 seconds: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

Comment: I'm not the decider of laws on stack overflow, so I'm not saying your question definitely falls into the off-topic category and that I'm definitely right. I'm just saying that's _probably_ why you aren't getting an answer

Comment: Yes, of course I have read through that. There are clear paths for adding languages, debuggers, etc. but I can't find references to adding file loaders. Core Visual Studio has this. Before I enter a feature request on GitHub I thought I would post here in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Btw - if this is really off topic to whoever makes those decisions (i didn't know if its you or not), I'm happy to remove this post in the interest of being a good citizen. I just don't understand why its a problem.

Comment: What about this specific part: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace Again, I'm not saying it's a problem - I was just trying to give you an insight as to why there may not be any responses to it.

Comment: Thanks, i think "workspace" is the term I need to pursue, not "projects" like core VS. I think this is as reasonable an answer as I can get, if you post as an answer I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking around it seems like you need to look at the "Workspace" section of the official API docs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_workspace

The `rootPath` variable takes a string argument, but there's nothing saying that it needs to be a *file* path so perhaps there's some wiggle room there.

That being said the `createFileSystemWatcher()` method appears to be set up to work with an actual file system. So even if you can get VSC to find files from somewhere like a database - you probably can't use any of the events that update the UI on changing a file.